# Jquery Page Redirect not Working

Tags: jquery, redirect

I was trying to redirect from one page to another using jquery.

My code is as follows:

```
<div>
    <button class="login-btn">Login</button>
</div>

<script src="../../jquery/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".login-btn").click(function (e) {
            console.log('here');
            var url = "http://stackoverflow.com";
            $(location).attr('href', url);
        });
    });
</script>
```

It prints "here" in the console, but it doesn't redirect to the stackoverflow page. There are no errors shown on the console as well. What could be the problem?

Comment: `$(location).attr('href', url);` Wow. Stop thinking that [jQuery will handle everything](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif) for you. Just do this: `location.href = url`

Comment: I tried, location.href = url. Doesn't work even with that.

Comment: @j08691 : Actually I was going through one of the solutions on
http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/03/how-to-redirect-user-to-another-web.html

Comment: @kartik - It works. http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/GB52j/show/

Comment: Oh, I got my mistake, the div tag was inside a <form runat='server'>.

The moment I put the <div> outside of the form it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do This :
window.location.href = url;